# Why do huskies have markings above their eyes

Tags: evolution, species-identification, microbiology, homework, dogs

[[image: You][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdw96.jpg).         Dogs in Antarctica pulling sleds

Comment: It's not just Huskies,  Many breeds - Rottweilers, Dobermans, Bernese - have them.  Others like German Shepherds may or may not have them as part of their coat color variation.

Comment: You may be able to get better answers at [pets.se].